# Windows エクスプローラの開くをフックする方法

Tags: windows

Windows エクスプローラの開くをフックするする方法はありますでしょうか？

実現したいことは、

Windowsのエクスプローラで、
サーバーにあるムービーなどのファイルを
開く動作(ダブルクリック、右クリック・開くなど）
をおこなった際に、サーバーの負荷を下げたい為、
一度 サーバーからローカルPCの適当な場所にファイルをコピーした後で、
レジストリに関連付けされているプログラムで開かれるようにしたいです。

ムービー判定は、拡張子判定avi、mp4、などでできれば問題ないと考えております。

Comment: serverの共有フォルダをエクスプローラで開いて、ダブルクリックすると、ローカルへコピーを行い、任意のアプリケーションで実行したいってことですよね？
フックというか、『ローカルにコピーして任意のアプリケーションを実行する』アプリケーションを作って関連付けてやるのが簡単なような気がしますけど...これserverの負荷下がりますかね？

Comment: ご意見ありがとうございます！
『ローカルにコピーして任意のアプリケーションを実行する』アプリを関連付けする方法ですが、
各ファイルとの関連付けを、別途アプリ側で管理する必要がでてきそうなので、使用者側の操作がが少々使う側が面倒かと思っております。
なのでなるべく関連付けはそのままにできたらといいかと思っております。

また負荷に関しては、サーバーが同時に複数アクセスなどもあるので、
複数ムービー再生でのシークを考慮すると、
一括でダウンロードさせるほうがよいかと考えております。
あと、また再度ムービーを見る場合でもローカルを参照させることもできてよいかなとも考えております。

Comment: 関連付けは「開く」以外の動詞も定義できますし、それをデフォルトに変更することもできます。ローカルだったらコピーしないとかも含めて、希望の動作をするアプリケーションを作ればいいだけのことでは？ それとは別に、「一括でダウンロード」とありますが、選択されていないファイルは操作されませんから、やはりその辺りも含めて、希望の動作をするアプリケーションを（ｒｙ